# Storing redis hget values into a variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

```
const redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Something went wrong ', err)
});


var getResponse = (key, field) =>{
 client.hget(key,field, function(err,reply){
    if(!err) return reply; 
    else {
    console.log(err);
    }
  });
};

var s = getResponse("employee","b");
console.log(s);
```

So when the output shows **undefined**. What am I doing wrong? How to store the return value to s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callbacks like:

```
var getResponse = (key, field, success, error) =>{
    client.hget(key,field, function(err,reply){
        if(!err) {
           success(reply);
         }
       else {
          error(err);
        }
   });
};

getResponse("employee","b",function success(reply){
    //here you get the reply
}, function error(err) {
        //error
});
```

If you are using Node version 6 or above you can use promise or async await. You can find more details on the following link: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html

Comment: I guess, my query want clear enough.  In my original code, if use <b>console,log(reply)</b>; instead of <b>return reply</b> it gives proper output. What I want is to store that output into a variable. How do I do that? Is there a data type mismatch?

Comment: if you want to store the reply value into a variable and after that manipulate it, you should do that in the success callback. The success callback is the place where you can be sure that you get the value. (async behavior).