# Using redis and node.js issue - Redis_client.hget return always false

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm running a simple web app backed by node.js, and I'm trying to use redis to store some key-pairs Json object and it store data into redis as I verify this on "**redis-cli**" console . But when I try to fetch data it return always false event with no error.

All I do is run "node index.js" on the command line, and here's the first few lines of my index.js:

```
const getRedisClient = () => {
  client = redis.createClient(REDIS["PORT"], REDIS["HOST"]);
  client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Redis Error " + err);
  });
  return client;
}

const getPostByLocalDbPath = (local_db_path, user_id) => {
  try {
    let client = getRedisClient();
    console.log("---- cache keys -----");
    console.log(user_id, local_db_path);
    let data = client.hget(user_id, local_db_path, function (err, obj) {
      if(err) {
        return null;
      }
      return obj;
    });
    console.log("--- cache data ---", data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("--- cache get exception ---", err);
    return {};
  }
}
```

When I call "getPostByLocalDbPath" method then it return false instead of data that I stored in redis cache.

When I run

> HGET 87 bdre2eb7-38b3-11e9-b66c-0af14c44c62s

command on redis-cli console then I can see the data against this key

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380414/storing-redis-hget-values-into-a-variable-in-nodejs

Comment: @griFlo But now its returning true instead of value

Comment: you have the data in the callback from `hget` and not outside. make a console.log before `return obj`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promisify:

```
var redis = require("redis");

const getRedisClient = () => {
  cl = redis.createClient();
  cl.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Redis Error " + err);
  });
  return cl;
}

let client = getRedisClient();
const {promisify} = require('util');
const hgetAsync = promisify(client.hget).bind(client);

async function getPostByLocalDbPath(local_db_path, user_id){
    console.log("---- cache keys -----");
    console.log(user_id, local_db_path);
    let data = await hgetAsync(user_id, local_db_path);
    console.log("--- cache data ---", data);
    return data;
}

getPostByLocalDbPath('bdre2eb7-38b3-11e9-b66c-0af14c44c62s', '87').then(
    val=>console.log(val)
);
```